# Is there a way to make a class castable to any object?

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming

I am having issues coming up with a good way to cast a class into any other class.
I am using groovy and I am trying to replace a third party library with a series of no-ops in order to provide it with dry run functionality.

Lets say I have a script like this:

```
class NoOp {
    List tree = []
    NoOp(List tree=[]){
        this.tree = tree
    }
    def invokeMethod(String name, Object args)  {
        return new NoOp(tree+name)
    }
}
class BigList {
    List getNewBigList(){
        return ['hello'] // I normally return a lot of stuff
    }
}

BigList.metaClass['getNewBigList']={->return new NoOp()}

List list = new BigList().getNewBigList()
// Each function should have a new instance of the NoOp class, causing the next to do nothing
list.iterator().collect{String x->
    return x // Marshall Data
}.each{
    // Do more stuff here
}
String a = list[0] // Should return a NoOp here

// Remove metaClass from new instances
GroovySystem.metaClassRegistry.removeMetaClass(BigList.class)
```

Theoretically this works fine (and does until groovy tries to cast a result), invokeMethod will return a new NoOp class to the function returns and causing any subsequent uses to also do nothing.

The problem comes down to casting. As soon `List l = new NoOp()` happens groovy will throw an error.
Is there a good way to allow NoOp to be cast to any type?

Note: This is just a dummy script, there could be any number of classes and packages that would be overwritten by the NoOp metaclass so doing it manually would not be feasible.

Comment: Just a few pointers: have you looked into overriding `def asType(Class c)` to solve your problem? If you want to override a wide variety I'd also look into using mock-libraries (they are usually used for tests as automatically generated stand-ins and might just be what you want here)?

Comment: Yes asType doesn't work well for this, first off it requires the use of 'as' otherwise it won't work with implicit conversions. Secondly, casting in general requires that you change the data type to the new format. For example in a string to list as type I might do something like. `return "string".split('')`

As for mocks I doubt they would work as needed. I am really trying to cast to any class that might pop up in a chain of functions. These could be Reader/Writer/Model/Support/Helper Classes